# How do I install/use the Dvorak keyboard layout in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu on my Nexus 4 on the 14.09 *stable* channel, the one thing I hate the most is that I cannot comfortably type on it. I'm a Dvorak user - how do I get this layout installed?

Thanks!